# Speed up embedded linux compilation process

Tags: performance, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, openwrt

Have an embedded linux (OpenWrt) project for custom hardware. Any changes in kernel or application require full image or application recompiling. And recompiling is painfully slow.
To reduce this pain bought AMD Threadripper 3970X based work station with 128Gb RAM and 1Tb SSD. Testbenches for this CPU shows 120 second of linux kernel compilation time.
But I got bigger compilation time.

Full image compilation first time reduced from:

[image]
to:
[image]

Repeated image compilation reduced from:

[image]
to: [image]

Package recompilation (`$ time make package/tensorflow/compile`) reduced from:

[image]
to:
[image]

E.g. compiling time reduced 2-7x.
During first image compilation all necessary source code to be downloaded from network. I have fast ethernet (100Mb/s) connection to not waist time for that.
I use RAMDISK:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk  
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,size=64G tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

to store all sources, object and temporary files so no IO losses I believe.

`make -j64` used to compile it. I see that all 64 cores loaded very rarely during compilation:

[image]

Mostly I see following:

[image]

or even this:
[image]

so I can't believe that faster compilation can't be achieved. Could someone give me hints/advices how to speed up GCC C/C++ cross compilation process. Some search points me to [distcc](https://github.com/distcc/distcc) and [Parallel GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ParallelGcc) but I doesn't have experience with it so not sure if this is what I need as OpenWrt [has almost nothing](https://openwrt.org/faq/how_can_i_speed_up_build_process) in their manuals explaining how to speed up build process.

Comment: This is a very hard question to answer without doing the entire exercise by ourselves. Can you show us a sample of the running build processes in the low CPU usage situation?

Comment: If most of your changes are localized, you should probably check out [Ccache](https://ccache.dev/). It fetches previously compiled binaries from a cache, if these should have been unchanged (i.e. same compiler, flags, source and includes, possibly being the same after preprocessing).

Comment: "fast ethernet" is really a bad name. It was named that to distinguish it from the first generation that ran at 0.01 Gbit/s. But even "fast ethernet" is only 0.1 Gbit/s; today the bare minimum is 1 Gbit/s. 10Gbit/s is easily available.

Comment: A pretty keen example of why pictures shouldn't be posted in questions. Every single one is dead for me, and I'm not about to click-through all of those. Taking advantage of 64 threads/cores/whatever is probably impossible because of dependencies in how the project is compiled. If Y needs X, Y can't compile in parallel with X. After ccache, you could try the painful process of modularizing your compilation so more units are independent, or at least reduce the depth of dependency trees if possible.

Comment: Install `ccache`. It speeds up a lot secondary builds.

Answer (score -1):

In linux, there is a concept of incremental build, so first time it will take time to build, but next time you need to build only the part which is changed or added extra. No need to rebuild everything. In that case build will be faster.

All the cores of the CPU will not be loaded all the times. It depends how many tasks are running currently. Suppose in your system, there are 8 cores but only 6 tasks are running. In that case all the cores will not be loaded fully.

Comment: What you describe is not exclusive to Linux at all.